# How do you put IIS web services into maintenance mode?

Tags: web-services, iis

How do you put web services into maintenance mode?

I've tried the `app_offline.htm`, doesn't seem to work well for web services. Does work for web site though.

`app_offline.htm` worked fine for web sites, but not for web service. When I called an web service function via code that's supposedly under maintenance (put the `app_offline.htm` under the root directory of the IIS web service), I still got the proper response as usual.

Ideally I would like the web service that's under maintenance to return to me a message like "under maintenance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your Global.asax as suggested by [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12777952/12744).  Then trigger it by setting a flag when you are in maintenance mode

In my opinion, when a service is unavailable, you should respond with a **503** Service Unavailable status; but you can do anything you like with the response.

Comment: I like this answer, but one caveat is that this requires (I think) ASP.Net compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Create a utility function for your web services, which checks for the presence of `app_offline.htm` at your website's root path, and responds accordingly.

Note that if you wanted to get fancy with it, you could use a part of the WCF pipeline (assuming you're using WCF and not the legacy .ASMX services) to modify your services/methods by using an attribute (eg, [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13655542/1001985)).